# Templating `bucket_key` in S3KeySensor in Apache Airflow

Tags: jinja2, airflow

Airflow version: 1.9.0

Within an airflow dag file, I have a `PythonOperator` task, named `run_query`, that sets the following xcom variable within its python_callable function:

`kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='query_result_loc', value=query_result_loc)`

Latter in that same dag, I have a `S3KeySensor` task that uses the above location for its bucket_key param:

```
S3KeySensor(task_id = 'check_file_in_s3',
                 bucket_key = '{{  ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="run_query",key="query_result_loc")  }}' ,
                 bucket_name = None,
                 wildcard_match = False,
                 poke_interval=60,
                 timeout=1200,
                 dag = dag
                 )
```

Now, when I run the dag (either in test mode or trigger_dag mode), S3KeySensor complains of a missing bucket_name, which comes from this code in [S3KeySensor definition](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-9-stable/airflow/operators/sensors.py):

```
    class S3KeySensor(BaseSensorOperator):
    """
    Waits for a key (a file-like instance on S3) to be present in a S3 bucket.
    S3 being a key/value it does not support folders. The path is just a key
    a resource.

    :param bucket_key: The key being waited on. Supports full s3:// style url
        or relative path from root level.
    :type bucket_key: str
    :param bucket_name: Name of the S3 bucket
    :type bucket_name: str
    :param wildcard_match: whether the bucket_key should be interpreted as a
        Unix wildcard pattern
    :type wildcard_match: bool
    :param aws_conn_id: a reference to the s3 connection
    :type aws_conn_id: str
    """
    template_fields = ('bucket_key', 'bucket_name')

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(
                self, bucket_key,
                bucket_name=None,
                wildcard_match=False,
                aws_conn_id='aws_default',
                *args, **kwargs):
            super(S3KeySensor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            # Parse
            if bucket_name is None:
                parsed_url = urlparse(bucket_key)
                if parsed_url.netloc == '':
                    raise AirflowException('Please provide a bucket_name')
                else:
                    bucket_name = parsed_url.netloc
                    if parsed_url.path[0] == '/':
                        bucket_key = parsed_url.path[1:]
                    else:
                        bucket_key = parsed_url.path
            self.bucket_name = bucket_name
            self.bucket_key = bucket_key
```

Looks like the template is not getting rendered at this stage.

If I comment out that if block, it works fine. Is this a bug or a wrong usage of template fields?

Update, based on @kaxil's comment:

- With no bucket_name provided and with the 'if' block left uncommented, airflow fails to even detect the dag. On the UI, I instead see this error: `Broken DAG: [/XXXX/YYYY/project_airflow.py] Please provide provide a bucket_name`
- With no bucket_name provided, but with the following modification to the 'if' block (cf. removed the `if parsed_url.netloc == ''` check), it works fine:

  ```
  if bucket_name is None:
      parsed_url = urlparse(bucket_key)
      bucket_name = parsed_url.netloc
      if parsed_url.path[0] == '/':
          bucket_key = parsed_url.path[1:]
      else:
          bucket_key = parsed_url.path
  ```
- With a bucket_name provided, it works fine with a rendered value for `bucket_key` and `bucket_name` under `Rendered Template` tab.

Comment: In the Airflow web UI, do you see any rendered templates in the page _Rendered Template_ for any of those tasks? Might be a good way to inspect the template rendering. If the field is templated and the variable is filled, it should work.

Comment: @tobi6 I do see the right substitution under the 'rendered template' tab on the dag run's UI.

Comment: @crackjack Can you update your question with the screenshot of Airflow Web UI -> Rendered template for both cases i) With bucket name, and ii) Without bucket name.

Comment: @kaxil I cant post a screenshot without masking the rendered values, which would defeat the purpose of your ask. Instead, I have tried to address your comment in my question. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @crackjack Can you provide the value of `bucket_key`? as in is it `s3://BUCKET_NAME/OBJECT_NAME.csv` format or is it `s3:///BUCKET_NAME/OBJECT_NAME.csv` ??? Don't provide the actual value but just let me know the format.

Comment: @kaxil The rendered template of `bucket_key` on the UI is of the right format ie. `s3://BUCKET_NAME/OBJECT_NAME.csv`

Comment: That is strange then.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably worked this out by now but it's because you're not providing an array to task_ids. The format should be `task_ids=["run_query"]`. Changing it to this resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly noticed with updated quote, bucket key validation happens before jinja templating.

The only solution I found to this is to not use functionality where you only provide bucket key. If you want to use templating, provide both bucket name and bucket key. In that case, validation won't happen and fields will be templated.